# MainController.xib file required for every project?

Tags: ios

Is a MainController.xib file required for every iOS project? Reason I ask is because I have started to work on some programs, and I noticed that with some of the defaults there is no MainController.xib file generated.

If it is not generated by the template, does this mean that I have to create one myself using "Add File?"

I have a vague recollection of reading somewhere that MainController.xib generated the first view when the program loads but am not sure if this is correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not required.  As far as I know, none of the templates in Xcode 4.2 and 4.3 create a `MainController.xib`.

Your app's `Info.plist` can contain the “Main nib file base name” key.  The raw key is `NSMainNibFile`, and it also shows up on the app's Summary screen as the “Main Interface” combo box.

If this key has the value `MainController`, then you need to have a nib named `MainController`.  The app will automatically load this when it is launched.  You can set the value of the key to something else if you want to name your main nib something else.  (I usually name mine `MainInterface`.)

If you don't include this key in your `Info.plist`, then the app won't automatically load a nib when it is launched.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a default name generated by XCode.  Depending on the project template, whatever the the .xib file is named, you get a controller to go with it.

Comment: Reason I ask is because one lesson I have been working on and debugging has MainController.xib and a ViewController.xib. Was wondering if one reason my code won't compile is because I don't have a MainController.xib? Should I add one just to see if it works?

Comment: @pdenlinger  Is this a view based application?  If so, there is usually MainWindow.xib, which doesn't need to be touched, and another .xib (usually the controllerName.xib) that holds the content.

Comment: @pdenlinger Check the appDelegate to make sure the proper view controller is getting instantiated with the proper .xib.  The methos to look for would be "initWithNibName:"

Comment: Sorry, I meant MainWindow.xib not MainController.xib. Yes, it is a single page view-based application. Yes, appDelegate has the method "initWithNibName" and has the correct xib name.

Comment: @pdenlinger Looks like rob mayoff's answer is the one to point you in the right direction.